# Trying to replace pendant light fitting to a chandelier light

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch, fitting

Can anyone help and advise how this setup is working without a switch live as I am trying to label these so I can easily put them in connectors so I can install my chandelier but unable to do it without understanding how this works and I assume the single connectors would work or do I need the block connectors?

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's a little hard to understand your question; would you edit in some sentences? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: Assuming the existing pendant works, why would you not simply disconnect it and connect the new chandelier in the same way?

Comment: It _looks_ like the blue and brown wires go down the shaft from which the pendant hangs. (I assume that there's a yellow/green ground wire in there too.) These would be the ones that provide power to the pendant. Disconnect them from the block, put the new chandelier up, connect the brown from the chandelier to where the brown pendant was, the blue to where the blue was and the ground to where the ground was. Oh, and tun off the power - FIRST

Comment: Thanks all but I am unable to fit the chandelier without first removing this pendant light fitting as this comes in the way of the chandelier fittings. My question was how to use connectors to fit the existing fittings in as I understand the neutral and Live wires but unable to locate the switch live wire so was hoping for some advice regarding how to wire this up in connectors and in which order. Thanks